# converting int to string for dropdownlistfor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an int property for Age, and a selectlist of possible ages to choose from.  When retrieving the data for editing, I am getting an error when adding the tostring() method that says:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

so my viewmodel looks like:

```
public int LowerAgeLimit { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> Ages { get; set; }
```

My query is retrieving the data correctly, and then in the view I am trying to have data displayed like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LowerAgeLimit.ToString()
                      , Model.CreateGroupForm.Ages
                      , new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Without the tostring() method, it displays blank which makes sense as it is expecting a string. But it won't let me convert to a string without the error.  I've also tried creating a new string Age property in the viewmodel, and converting the int to a string in the query, but I still can't get the dropdownlist to display the value.

In the query I have populated the ages list as follows:

```
model.CreateGroupForm.Ages.Insert(0, (new SelectListItem { Text = "", Value = "" }));
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {

            model.CreateGroupForm.Ages.Insert(i, (new SelectListItem {Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString()}));
        }
```

Comment: You do not need .ToString() - conversion to int is handled automatically by the model binder.  I have plenty of occurrences of Html.DropDownListFor with integer parameters.

Comment: ok good to know, any idea why it's not displaying the data then?

Comment: I think you need to show us how you populate Model.CreateGroupForm.Ages

Answer (score 2):

I've created a new MVC project and tried the following: 
Model:

```
 public class Test
{

    public int LowerAgeLimit { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Ages
    {
        get;set;
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Test
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LowerAgeLimit, Model.Ages)
```

Controller:

```
      public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Test tst = new Test();

        tst.Ages = new List<SelectListItem>();
        tst.Ages.Insert(0, (new SelectListItem { Text = "", Value = "" }));
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            tst.Ages.Insert(i, new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString() });
        }


        return View(tst);
    }
```

**EDIT:**
After you've updated the way Ages list is populated my dropdown is still working, but with an empty value being the first one in the dropdown. Check the edited controller.

[image: Here's the result]

Comment: I have edited the OP with how I'm populating the ages list.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're adding a dummy row at the start of the ages list - this is unnecessary.  Try making the following changes:

Model:

```
[Required]
public int? LowerAgeLimit { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LowerAgeLimit.ToString()
                  , Model.CreateGroupForm.Ages
                  , new { @class = "form-control" },
                  , "(Choose)")
```

Controller:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
    model.CreateGroupForm.Ages.Add(new SelectListItem {Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString()});
}
```

The 4th parameter of DropDownListFor controls what the "dummy" entry should be, and ensures that it maps to null on the model (the Required attribute will ensure something is selected).

Alternatively, you could just use a number control for this!

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LowerAgeLimit, 
    new { @class = "form-control", type = "number", min = "1", max = "99"})
```

Comment: thanks for all the ideas, unfortunately it's still not working using suggested solutions. Will discuss over a skype with someone as there must be something funny going on in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Your ViewModel:

```
public int LowerAgeLimit { get; set; }
public SelectList Ages { get; set; }
```

To populate, try this:

```
var items = new List<SelectListItem>();
items.Insert(0, (new SelectListItem { Text = "", Value = "" }));
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{

    items.Insert(i, (new SelectListItem {Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString()}));
}

model.CreateGroupForm.Ages = new SelectList (items, "Value", "Text", null);
```

Your View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LowerAgeLimit, (SelectList)Model.CreateGroupForm.Ages, new { @class = "form-control" })
```